# Make graph with google visualization with two arrays

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

Hi I want to make a graph from data in a database using google visualization here is the code i am using:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_name", "db_pass", "db_table");     
if(!$connect ) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';



$tempsql="SELECT `temperature` FROM `apidata`";
$resulttemp = $connect->query($tempsql);
$temp=array();
foreach ($resulttemp as $rowtemp){
    $temp[]=$rowtemp;
}
$resulttemp->close();

$idsql="SELECT `id` FROM `apidata`";
$resultid = $connect->query($idsql);
$id=array();
foreach ($resultid as $rowid){
    $id[]=$rowid;
}
$resultid->close();

$js_arrayTemp = json_encode($temp);
//echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
$js_arrayId=json_encode($id);
//echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array2 . ";\n";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var Temp = <?php echo $js_arrayTemp;?>;
  var id = <?php echo $js_arrayId;?>;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'id');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temp');

  for(i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
    data.addRow([id[i], Temp[i]]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {});
}

</script>
```

When i look at my website there is no graph. But in the debugger i can see the data
[Pictue of debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1G5k.png)
[Picture og debugger 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMOKL.png)
Hope someone can see my problem.

Answer (score 0):

can't use an object as a column value, here...

```
data.addRow([id[i], Temp[i]]);
```

where `Temp[i]` = `{"temperature": "6"}`

instead, get the value of the object...

```
data.addRow([parseInt(id[i].id), parseFloat(Temp[i].temperature)]);
```